# Rails 4: after_find and includes conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include

In my `Order` model I have a has_many association:

```
has_many :suborders, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order
```

However, after finding records I must do some preprocessing so I also have a `after_find` callback like:

```
after_find :verify_validity
def verify_validity
   order.suborders.each do |suborder|
      ... doing something here with suborders ...
   end
end
```

When I try to eager load a batch of orders with their suborders, however, I get duplicates:

In controller:

```
@orders = Order.active.order(:updated_at => :desc).includes(:suborders)
```

In view:

```
Order is <%= order.inspect %>
<br />
Order suborders are <%= order.suborders.inspect %>
```

And I get

```
Order is #<Order id: 1126, ...>
Order suborders are #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Suborder id: 119, order_id: 1126...>, #<Suborder id: 119, order_id: 1126...>]>
```

How to avoid getting such duplicates?

EDIT: I also noticed that the system is doing the same query twice (first time in `after_find` and then again because of `includes`). How to make `after_find` use the results of the `includes`? The one in the `after_find` is highly inefficient (n+1 queries).

Comment: Why are you validating in the `order` model? Why not add the " ... doing something here with suborders ..." to `Suborder` model?

Comment: @RichPeck it's not a validation: it's an update to the order model based on its suborders. And I need to do it every time I load it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`order.suborders.uniq.inspect`

[Here's a post about it](https://venkatev.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/activerecord_joins_and_include/) that might give you some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks. This does work. However, this doesn't resolve the issue of the number of queries executed.